# Console of ESP01 flashed with Micropython 1.17 can't be accessed

Tags: esp8266, micropython, esp01

I was able to flash my ESP01 (1MB of Flash) with micropython:

```
esptool.py --port $PORT erase_flash
esptool.py --chip auto --port $PORT write_flash -z 0x000000 $IMAGE


esptool.py v2.8
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-1463430
Connecting........_____....._____.....___
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: e8:db:84:a8:ba:f7
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 1.9s
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-1463430
Connecting........_
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: e8:db:84:a8:ba:f7
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 1MB
Flash params set to 0x0020
Compressed 589912 bytes to 389772...
Wrote 589912 bytes (389772 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 37.8 seconds (effective 125.0 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

There was no error. I used both Thonny and "Mu Editor" in order to attempt to access the REPL but without luck.

I can connect to the device via picocom, but I am stuck on the following "screen":

```
port is        : /dev/cu.usbserial-1463430
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
stopbits are   : 1
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
hangup is      : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv -E
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
logfile is     : none
initstring     : none
exit_after is  : not set
exit is        : no

Type [C-a] [C-h] to see available commands
Terminal ready
```

I would expect to be able to "CTRL + C" here right into the python shell. But that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting the RST pin to GND did fix the problem. Hitting the Reset button in Thonny did not do the trick here.